# Count occurence in a list with time complexity of O(nlogn)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

This is what I have so far:

```
alist=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,3,2,2,1]
def icount(alist):
    adic={}
    for i in alist:
        adic[i]=alist.count(i)
    return adic

print(icount(alist))
```

I did some research to find out that the time complexity of list.count() is O(n), thus , this code will be O(n^2).

Is there a way to reduce this to O(nlogn)?

Comment: See [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It's there for exactly this kind of work.

Comment: If you just increment `adic[i]`, the complexity should be O(n).

Comment: But how do I know the time complexity of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Counter` like this

```
from collections import Counter
alist=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,3,2,2,1]
print Counter(alist)
```

If you want to use your solution, you can improve it like this

```
def icount(alist):
    adic = {}
    for i in alist:
        adic[i] = adic.get(i, 0) + 1
    return adic
```

Even better, you can use `defaultdict` like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
adic = defaultdict(int)
for i in alist:
    adic[i] += 1
return adic
```

Also, You might want to look at the Time Complexity of various operations on different Python objects [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: `get` is a function of a list data type right? alist.get(2,0) gives me an error

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Sorry. Fixed it. Please check now :)

Comment: Can you explain me what exactly it does?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh It will try and get value for the first param in the dict, if it doesn't exist, it simply returns the second parameter.

Comment: So if I am right, is this the shorter version of:

`if i in adic:
    adic[i] += 1
else:
    adic[i] = 1`

??

Comment: @thefourtheye It works prefectly. But how do I know its time complexity?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Exactly

Comment: @D.X.D You might want to look at the Time Complexity of various operations on different Python objects here https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 6):

Counter is your helper:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [1,2,1,3,4]
>>>  Counter(a)
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
>>> x = Counter(a)     
>>> x[1]
2
>>> x[2]
1
```

Get the count of each element easily through this method